# Can't Import Django using Python3 on macOS Sierra

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Have both versions of Python (Legacy 2.7.10 and 3.6.2) installed on macOS Sierra.

Installed pip using the following steps.

Downloaded it using curl:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

Installed pip it by running the installer script:

```
sudo python get-pip.py
```

Checked for any upgrades / updates for pip:

```
sudo pip install -U pip
```

Installed django 1.11:

```
sudo pip install django==1.11
```

When I run python (legacy):

```
python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb  7 2017, 00:08:15) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> print(django.get_version())
1.11
```

However, when trying it using python3:

```
python3
Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5926, Jul 16 2017, 20:11:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

**Note:** I followed a different tutorial and got python3 working with django 1.11 using virtualenv - please don't suggest this as I am new to the python world and just want to use python3 / django 1.11 in a non-virtual environment - I just want have it working like the legacy python interpreter is behaving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pip` installs libraries differently for python2 and python3, so you effectively have different environments for each. If you want to install Django for python3, you'll want to install it like this:

`pip3 install django==1.11`